# Geb - Selenium Input focus with datepicker

Tags: grails, selenium, functional-testing, geb, xvfb

Since upgrading to Geb 0.12.2 and Selenium 2.48.2, I cant get the following to work:

```
$("form").validOn(dateString)
```

I have tried variations like:

```
$("input",name:"validOn").value(dateString)
```

and

```
$("form").validOn << Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a")
$("form").validOn << Keys.chord(Keys.DELETE)
if(date){
  $("form").validOn << date
}
```

The element I am trying to set is using a jquery datepicker:

```
  <form class="form-inline">
        <label>Valid On:</label> 
        <input size="10" type="text"  id="datepicker-validOn" name="validOn" value="${validOn}">
...
   </form>
..
..
    <r:script type="text/javascript">

        $("#datepicker-validOn").datepicker({
            format:"${session.sessionPreferences?.globalDatepickerFormat}"
        });
...
```

The datepicker is opened which means that selecting the field works, but the string value is not placed inside the input field. I suspect that this has to do with the focus moving to the datepicker, but have not found a way to fix it. I tried having two `.value(dateString)` hoping that the second will return focus to the field but this has not worked. Also, the original html is not altered by the datepicker.

I am using firefox 33.1.1
**This only happens on headless environment, using Hudson with Xvfb to run the functional tests.** Running locally on desktop with same version of firefox works as expected, using this format : `$("input",name:"validOn").value(dateString)`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the resolution for Xvfb from 1024x1024x24 to 1600x1200x24 has fixed the issue.. Not sure how this could affect the element focusing, but apparently it does.